# How to send multiple timeframe data from MQL4 to a Node.js?

Tags: node.js, distributed-computing, mql4

I am trying to get multiple time-frame data of different trading instrument ( `_Symbol` ) from MetaTrader4 Terminal to a node.

How can I do it?

Can we do it from the same EA inside a MetaTrader4 Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

`iOpen(Symbol(),PERIOD_M1,1)`  - is the way to get data from M1 ( last bar ), if you need another timeframe - replace `PERIOD_M1` with another `ENUM_TIMEFRAMES`. So what is the problem? Usually StackOverflow requires to see your MCVE-based example to help you.

Comment: You might want to know, that your post contains an error. The syntax, as posted, will never get you a piece of the last bar data. It might be a reason to reconsider the text and edit the text ( which, b.t.w. does not answer what KAJI has actually asked about ). You may face some other kind of responses from StackOverflow Administrators, who may react and would most probably consider such an original text as just a comment, so some edit / rework is obviously a good idea. Brgds.

Comment: Of course if someone needs the real-time data, then need to request iClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,0), for accessing the past data (e.g., once some timeframe  delivered a new bar) - need to get OHLC data, example of that (just Open) - I think is reported correctly

Comment: Well, not enough, Daniel. The O/P wanted to source details form much more trading instruments, than the very one, MT4.Graph.local, `_Symbol` per-se. So still more efforts are needed to be harnessed for an adequate & feasible algorithmisation of all such non-trivial requirements.

Comment: acutally i have done this..

 void OnTick() 
{
   string newData[20];
 string a = TimeToStr(TimeGMT()) + "," + Bid + "," + Ask + "," + Open[0];
if(NewBar()) {
 Print("New bar");
 for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
     newData[i] = TimeToStr(iTime("EURUSD",PERIOD_M5,i)) + "," +iOpen("EURUSD",PERIOD_M5,i) + "," + iHigh("EURUSD",PERIOD_M5,i)+ "," + iLow("EURUSD",PERIOD_M5,i)+ "," + iClose("EURUSD",PERIOD_M5,i);
         a += "," + newData[i];
               }
   }
I want to send different product different timeframe open high low and close

Comment: yes, something like that. StringFormat may help you to write less

Answer (score 0):

### A.1: Yes, we can.

### A.2: No, that initial idea is not a good one.

While the intention is clear, the idea to use a single EA to send live-data for multiple trading instruments is not working for the said interest well.

MQL4 code-execution environment has some fixed, hard-wired internal logic and due to these + plus due to the reality, how Capital Markets and Broker-type Market access mediators work, the solo-EA will never fit these requirements.

A simple call to

```
iOpen( aTradingInstrumentSymbolNAME,       // iHigh, iLow, iClose, iVolume, iTime
       aSelectedTimeFrameDefinedCODE,
       aRelativeBarPTR
       )
```

is by far not enough.

Professional solution will require a lot of care for a real-time handling capabilities, for unmasking the actual flow of mutually hiding events, for achieving minimalistic processing latencies, so a quite high engineering expertise will be needed.

Start with learning the basics about Scripts, benchmark all your critical code-sections with recording their actual durations in [us] and assure, your code will remain non-blocking under all circumstances. This will decide, whether more than one code-execution thread(s) will be necessary in prime-time / for peak-hour.

Having managed that, your way just started to lead in a direction towards your expected result.

Next one has to decide about a feasible inter-process / distributed-computing data-flow and signalling, needed for inter-platform integration.

Last, but not least, important point is the legal-side of such undertaking. It depends both on your local juri§$§$§diction and Broker's Terms & Conditions as no one would enjoy to celebrate a technically well mastered Project from inside of jail.

All that, quite an interesting Project.